# netstat shows foreign address starting with static and incomplete ip

Tags: database, networking, amazon-web-services, netstat

I'm trying to identify what is using a large amount of network bandwidth that is degrading the performance of my DB.

I've run netstat -ta and keep seeing a foreign ip with something like: static-142-154-43:34860.

Why is this ip address incomplete?  Also what is the static prefix?

I'm just trying to find the culprit for excessive usage of the DB.

Servers are on AWS.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
netstat -n
```

which will display the ip addresses for all active TCP connections and not attempt to determine the names, as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat